# Why are my programmatically instantiated Prefabs not firing mouse events?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I'm instantiating 20 Prefabs. These prefabs have box colliders and an attached script that includes:

```
private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    print($"Mouse Enter detected by: {this.name}");
}
```

However these events never fire. If you google this issue you'll find multiple [posts](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mouse-events-on-instantiated-prefab-dont-trigger.30883/) about this going back more than a decade. Unfortunately none of those threads seem to include a solution. If I drag the Prefab into the scene the mouse events will work, but if I create them programmatically they do not. Can someone explain to me how I can get mouse events working on programmatically created prefabs?

EDIT:

Since someone asked for my instantiation code here it is:

```
foreach (var movie in movies.Select((value, index) => (value, index)))
    {
        float angle = movie.index * Mathf.PI * 2 / movies.Count;
        float x = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
        Vector3 pos = transform.position + new Vector3(x, height, z);
        float angleDegrees = -angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleDegrees, 0);
        var pre = Instantiate(moviePrefab, pos, rot, carousel.transform);
        pre.transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);
    }
```

Comment: Are the objects active? Is the script with the above function attached?  Is there another collider blocking camera sight to the objects?  Tested in 2020.3.0f1 with no issue.

Comment: How are you creating them programmatically?

Comment: I'm new to Unity and not familiar with active/inactive gameObjects. How would I tell between the two states?

Comment: If they're visible the game objects are active, but the script on them might not be. You need to have check box in the upper-left corner of the game object and script ticked.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give me many details but I made what you want to do and this is how.

1. I made two classes:

- NewBehaviourScript - for instatiating prefabs

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Prefab;
    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(Prefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x + i, transform.position.y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

- PrefabScript - script for prefab

```
public class PrefabScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
}
```

2. I created empty object "InstatiateObjectsHelper" in scene with the NewBehaviourScript
   [image]
3. Then I created a prefab by creating it in the hierarchy, added to it PrefabScript, added to it BoxCollider, and then dragged & dropped it into the assets window.

[image]

4. Pressed play and tested it and it is working how you want it to.